# Maintaining horizontal and vertical positioning of sibling elements in a flex row

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, flexbox, vue-transitions

I have 5 svgs in a line on a navbar.
When an icon is clicked, it transforms into it's larger version, but when that change happens all of the siblings shift vertically.

Is there a way to stop that from happening?
A way for the surrounding flex elements to maintain their exact vertical and horizontal poisitoning?

**codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/bubble-bar-v3-o3272?file=/src/components/BubbleBar.vue

**bubblebar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="bubble-bar">
    <svg
      ref="bar"
      class="_bar"
      width="672"
      height="100"
      viewBox="0 0 672 81"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M404.3 24.0003C373.5 19 363.5 0 333.5 0C303.5 0 291.001 18.5 265.609 24.0003C254.501 25.5003 192.187 23.2827 0 24.6007V80.5H672V24.6007L404.5 24.0003Z"
        fill="#D2CBFF"
      />
    </svg>

    <div class="_navbar">
      <div class="_icons">
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <div v-if="jobsShow" key="one" @click="jobsClicked">
            <img src="/jobs-active.svg" class="_svg" />
          </div>
          <div v-else key="two" @click="jobsClicked">
            <img src="/jobs.svg" class="_svg _jobs" />
          </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <div v-if="trendsShow" key="one" @click="trendsClicked">
            <img src="/trends-active.svg" class="_svg" />
          </div>
          <div v-else key="two" @click="trendsClicked">
            <img src="/trends.svg" class="_svg _trends" />
          </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <div v-if="castShow" key="one" @click="castClicked">
            <img src="/cast-active.svg" class="_svg" />
          </div>
          <div v-else key="two" @click="castClicked">
            <img src="/cast.svg" class="_svg _cast" />
          </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <div v-if="messagesShow" key="one" @click="messagesClicked">
            <img src="/messages-active.svg" class="_svg" />
          </div>
          <div v-else key="two" @click="messagesClicked">
            <img src="/messages.svg" class="_svg _messages" />
          </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <div v-if="profileShow" key="one" @click="profileClicked">
            <img src="/profile-active.svg" class="_svg" />
          </div>
          <div v-else key="two" @click="profileClicked">
            <img src="/profile.svg" class="_svg _profile" />
          </div>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BubbleBar",
  data() {
    return {
      jobsActive: true,
      trendsActive: false,
      castActive: false,
      messagesActive: false,
      profileActive: false,
      jobsShow: true,
      trendsShow: false,
      castShow: false,
      messagesShow: false,
      profileShow: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    jobsClicked() {
      this.jobsShow = true;
      this.trendsShow = false;
      this.castShow = false;
      this.messagesShow = false;
      this.profileShow = false;
      this.$refs.bar.style.transform = "translateX(-6px)";
    },
    trendsClicked() {
      this.jobsShow = false;
      this.trendsShow = true;
      this.castShow = false;
      this.messagesShow = false;
      this.profileShow = false;
      this.$refs.bar.style.transform = "translateX(72px)";
    },
    castClicked() {
      this.jobsShow = false;
      this.trendsShow = false;
      this.castShow = true;
      this.messagesShow = false;
      this.profileShow = false;
      this.$refs.bar.style.transform = "translateX(144px)";
    },
    messagesClicked() {
      this.jobsShow = false;
      this.trendsShow = false;
      this.castShow = false;
      this.messagesShow = true;
      this.profileShow = false;
      this.$refs.bar.style.transform = "translateX(218px)";
    },
    profileClicked() {
      this.jobsShow = false;
      this.trendsShow = false;
      this.castShow = false;
      this.messagesShow = false;
      this.profileShow = true;
      this.$refs.bar.style.transform = "translateX(292px)";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.bubble-bar
  display: flex
  align-items: flex-end
  position: relative
  width: 375px
  height: 600px
  border: solid 5px black
  overflow: hidden
._bar
  position: absolute
  bottom: -10px
  left: -294px
  z-index: 1
._navbar
  width: 100%
  bottom: 5px
  position: absolute
  z-index: 2
._icons
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-around
  align-items: center

._icons>*
  flex: 1

  ._svg
    cursor: pointer

  ._jobs,
  ._trends,
  ._cast,
  ._messages,
  ._profile
    margin-top: 20px

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active
  transition: opacity .25s

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to
  opacity: 0
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your larger icon is not rendered in between transitions. You can add a add a set height to the `_icons` class.

```
._icons
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-around
  align-items: center
  min-height: 65px
```